# StackExchange.Redis with Redis Cluster: PubSub always consuming from one shard

Tags: c#, redis, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster

I am using the StackExchange.Redis library in C# and have come across an issue related to Redis Cluster and PubSub functionality.

**Setup**

- Redis Cluster with multiple shards.
- Many subscribers in the system using PubSub.

**Problem:**
I've observed that when I subscribe to messages in a PubSub channel, the clients always consume messages from one specific shard. This results in that particular shard becoming overloaded, even though I have many subscribers distributed in my system.

**Understanding:**
Based on the official Redis documentation, PubSub is designed to work such that you can publish messages to any shard. These messages will then be propagated automatically to all other shards, allowing subscribers to consume messages from any shard.

It seems that StackExchange.Redis is not respecting this behavior.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any configuration within StackExchange.Redis that I might be missing to distribute the PubSub consumption across shards?
2. Is this behavior a known limitation of the StackExchange.Redis library when used with a Redis Cluster?

**Code Sample**

Code for subscribing:

```
string connectionString = "...";
string channelName = "...";
var connection = await ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync(connectionString);

var channelMessageQueue = connection.GetSubscriber().Subscribe(channelName);
channelMessageQueue.OnMessage(message =>
{
    // process my message
});
```

Code for sending:
`await connection.GetDatabase().PublishAsync(channelName, "hello");`

Any help or insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share a pubsub code sample?

Comment: @Haney I added code to the question.

Comment: you're doing everything right re: code to sub. How are you observing it all coming from one shard?

Comment: We are doing load test with many compute instances subscribing to the same PubSub channel and we see in the telemetry that only one shard is getting all the load.
I look inside the code: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/2e9e8e969552b0a0ba7c1baff615d363847e2769/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisSubscriber.cs#L430C1-L431C62

Looks like the library is trying to identify server based on the channel using multiplexer.SelectServer(). It tries to compute slot from the channel but the channels are not assigned to the slots.

Answer (score 0):

In a cluster environment, we need to have *some* strategy for how we route commands. With commands that involve a *key*, this is done for us: we perform the CRC-16 hash-slot operation (accounting for hash-tags), and we use *that* slot. But (at least until `SSUBSCRIBE`/`SPUBLISH` in Redis 7), the routing for *channels* is basically (as you note) open - you can subscribe anywhere, and messages are propagated horizontally (to other shards) as well as vertically (to replicas). Given that we *can* subscribe anywhere, the library needs to decide where it *will* route that message (for any of `SUBSCRIBE`, `PSUBSCRIBE` or `PUBLISH`).

The library currently assumes that you will be using multiple channels, and wants to distribute pub/sub load by *distributing channels*. To do this, it routes channels as though they are keys (incidentally, this is the same logic that `SSUBSCRIBE` and `SPUBLISH` use in Redis 7, noting that `SPUBLISH` is not propagated horizontally to other shards, because *no other shard should have listeners* - this is to reduce server cross-chatter in pub/sub heavy workloads). A consequence of this, as you have observed, is that if you're using only a single channel: all load will be focused on a single shard. Given the high throughput capabilities of Redis pub/sub, this is usually absolutely fine - indeed, it is the direction that Redis itself is choosing to head, via `SSUBSCRIBE`/`SPUBLISH`.

If there are genuine scenarios where this is a problem, I would be open to adding a new `CommandFlags` option that is basically "roll a dice" for pub/sub routing. However, before going *too far* down that road I'd like to understand the scenario a bit more (and in particular, any negative symptoms that you're seeing).